# How to store user specific data in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find some information on this, but I'm not sure where to look or how to phrase it.

I've madea simple app to learn PHP. However, the entire app is user-specific (you login to view your own posts).

Where should I store the user data, and the post data? For example, I would need to store `post_title, post_content, post_id, post_time, post_status`, and the user would have `user_name, user_password, user_email`.

Should these be in separate tables, or together? What is the common method for storing this kind of data?

Comment: Take a look at the database schema for WordPress. It has all this stuff in it. http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have the details in a separate user table.

```
User ID | User Name | Full Name | Email Address
```

And the `User ID` field is unique. Now you need to store your posts in another table:

```
Post ID | Post Subject | Post Content | Post Time | Post Status | Author
```

And this `Author` is a foreign key, and should be linked with the `User ID` field of Users table. This is called Relational Database. A relation can be made as this:

[image]

If you see in this table, the `User ID` and `Post ID` are unique keys. They are called Primary Keys, which means, each row is identified by that value. Also, the main reason for using this is, to avoid redundancy among the user values and also, this saves a huge amount of space occupied. :)

The SQL for this is:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    `User ID` int PRIMARY KEY,
    `User Name` varchar(255),
    `Full Name` varchar(255),
    `Email Address` varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Users (
  `User ID`, `User Name`, `Full Name`, `Email Address`
) VALUES (
  NULL, 'Username', 'Full Name', 'email@gmail.com'
);

CREATE TABLE Posts (
  `Post ID` int PRIMARY KEY,
  `Post Subject` varchar(255),
  `Post Content` TEXT,
  `User ID` int
);

INSERT INTO Posts (
  `Post ID`, `Post Subject`, `Post Content`, `User ID`
) VALUES (
  1, 'Hello World', 'Hello World', 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've never heard the term foreign key before. Is that just a number that is unique, and can be used in another tables?

Comment: Yes... You need to use that way... :) The `User ID` is unique and it is called Primary Key.

Comment: Good explanation, bad example in your diagram.  Students and courses would be many to many.

Comment: @DanBracuk Can you suggest me a better picture? I wanna create the same for it, but takes time.

Comment: Thanks!! For reference, should something like author_id/post_id be primary, or unique? (I assume it needs to be both)

Comment: Yes, that's called Primary key and I have explained that also! :)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I am using the NoSQL database MongoDB.  is it better to store user information and their posts in a single JSON document in a collection?. Because every time a user makes a request they only need to perform some action on their data only. which is a better way to go? and a separate question, How on the Back end side for each received API request we identify which particular logged-in user is making that API request. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: put the user info in one table with a unique key for each user. Then use this unique key to tag each 'post'. You can get fancy with 'comments' and 'edits' for each post later on. (hint - each post has a unique key also)

More complicated answer: read about database [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: That wiki page is pretty complicated.  I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  It might make it simpler to understand normalization.